# Problem with private property in class c++

Tags: c++

in .h file, I have promise and future classes.

```
template<class P> class promise
{
    P retVal;
public:
    void set_value(P val);
    future<P>* get_future();
};

template<class F> class future
{
public:
    promise<F> *fPromise;
public:
    F get();
};

template class promise<int>;
template class future<int>;
template class promise<long double>;
template class future<long double>;
```

and made classes as following in .CPP file

```
#include "lib.h"
namespace std
{
    template<class P>
    future<P> tmp = *(new future<P>);
    template<class F>
    F future<F>::get(){
        return this->fPromise->retVal;
    }

    template <class P>
    void promise <P>::set_value(P val) {
        this->retVal = val;
    }

    template <class P>
    future<P>* promise<P>::get_future() {
        tmp<P>.fPromise = this;
        return &tmp<P>;
    }
}
```

but in the main .cpp file when I want to work with classes I faced an error.

```
#include "lib.h"
using namespace std;
void func(promise<int> *prom, int varC){
    int res = 20;
    prom->set_value(res);
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    int res;
    promise<int> myp;
    future<int> myf = *(myp.get_future());
    thread(func, &myp1,4);
    res = var + myf.get();
    return res;
}
```

```
FuturePromise.cpp:8:24: error: ‘long double std::promise<long double>::retVal’ is private within this 
context
return this->fPromise->retVal;
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~
In file included from FuturePromise.cpp:1:0:
lib.h:11:3: note: declared private here
P retVal;
```

When I declare retVal as Public it works but I should make it private. How can I make it private? I aslo should made promise  * fPromise  in .h file private but it made the same error.

Comment: If it must be private then you need an accessor function to retrieve it - either a normal getXXX() accessor or an overloaded operator (the function call operator and the cast operator, for example)  The thing I am surprised about is that `promise<F> *fPromise;` is public

Comment: I have this problem with promise<F> *fPromise; too. it should be private. But It made the same error. you are right about promise<F> *fPromise.

Comment: Why do you expect a `future` can access the `private` portions of a `promise`?  You haven't set up any `friend` access.

Comment: `namespace ::std` is reserved.

Comment: `*(new future<P>)` is a memory leak, you just need `template<class P> future<P> tmp{};`.